# Remove previous route and add new one

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-maps-markers

I have a application containing a map activity which has plenty of markers from my SQLite database and a polyline connecting those markers.
The problem begins when I want to show a route between any clicked marker and my Location.
Problem is it works fine and shows the route for the first time but if any other marker is clicked, a new route is generated without removing previous route.

I know the problem is the following code.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
            HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            points.add(position);
        }
        lineOptions.addAll(points);
        lineOptions.width(5);
        lineOptions.color(Color.WHITE);
    }
      // googleMap.clear();
       //setMarkersPolyLines();
       googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);

}
```

My efforts till now:

1. Googled it and found a way using `polyline.remove();` but the problem is if placed after `addPolyline` then newly created route is also removed and if placed before that then error comes saying polyline might not be initialised.
2. Tried with if else as

   ```
   if(flag==0){
    polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    flag++;
   }
   else if(flag>0)
    polyline.remove();
    polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
   }
   ```

   but nothing happened.
3. Tried these steps but it causes a glitch/fluctuation kind of thing and also some delay.

   ```
     googleMap.clear();
     setMarkersPolyLines(); //setting all my markers again 
     googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
   ```
4. Atlast, tried initialising `points` and `lineoptions` in the for loop but again *might not be initialised* error and can't set to null as giving `nullPointerException` as `PolylineOptions` can't be set to null.

I tried many posts but nothing really was working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified Josef Adamcik's answer and it should work.

```
boolean isSecond = false;
private Polyline lastPolyline;    
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
            HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            points.add(position);
        }
        lineOptions.addAll(points);
        lineOptions.width(5);
        lineOptions.color(Color.WHITE);
    }    
    if(isSecond) {
            lastPolyline.remove();
            lastPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            lastPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            isSecond=true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a reference to a polyline created in last rendering. This reference should be a field of your class. You should call remove before add but only when lastPolyline is not null.

```
private Polyline lastPolyline;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
            HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            points.add(position);
        }
        lineOptions.addAll(points);
        lineOptions.width(5);
        lineOptions.color(Color.WHITE);
    }
      // googleMap.clear();
       //setMarkersPolyLines();
    if (lastPolyline != null) {
        lastPolyline.remove();
    }  
    lastPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro but even after clean, rebuild and reinstalling the app, nothing happened.